# How to wrap 'apostrophe-rich-text' value in tags other than p by default?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

What I am trying to do is have an editable `h3` without the ability to change styles. I've tried the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
{{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'name', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
   toolbar: ['Styles'],
   styles: [
     { name: 'Title', element: 'h3', attributes: {class: 'profileTitle'} }
   ],
   controls: {
     movable: false
   }
}) }}
</div>
```

What I would like to do is remove the `toolbar: ['Styles']` option so the ui does not render the styles dropdown and just have the text render inside the `h3` tags.

i.e. `<div class="wrapper"><h3 class="profileTitle">User Input Text</h3></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the Rich Text Editor at all, you can add a custom schema field (type `string`) and have the user edit the text in the modal instead.

See [How to enter non-rich-text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374782/how-to-enter-non-rich-text?rq=1) for a related question with answer. As the answer states, this is (currently) not possible in contextual editing.

Another approach might be to pass `autoParagraph` or `enterMode` to the CKEditor, see https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode

I hope that helps!